# Can't update MacPorts after upgrading to Mavericks

Tags: macports

I ran `port selfupdate` and MacPorts tried to upgrade itself to version 2.2.1, but eventually fails. When I add the `-v` flag, I can see the build fails after these lines:

```
checking for Tcl configuration... configure: error: Can't find Tcl configuration definitions
Command failed: cd     /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base && CC=/usr/bin/cc OBJC=/usr/bin/cc ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-tclpackage=/Library/Tcl --with-install-user=root --with-install-group=admin --with-directory-mode=0755 --enable-readline && make SELFUPDATING=1 && make install SELFUPDATING=1
Exit code: 1
```

How can I get MacPorts back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the command line tools Xcode installs. For whatever reason, Xcode doesn't seem to want to update them itself, but you can force it by running `xcode-select --install`. This will pop open a GUI prompt; select "Install" and let the installer do its thing. After this, MacPorts should build itself successfully. (You may need to rehash first; `rehash` in tcsh, `hash -r` in bash and zsh (I think).)

Answer (score 0):

I installed the ActiveTCL distribution from Active State. I vaguely recalled it was necessary; I just bought a new machine, has Mavericks, and I put the ActiveState TCL distro on it as a matter of habit prior to rebuilding my MacPorts install.

Comment: So it had Mavericks out-of-the-box, right? You didn't need to upgrade? I'd imagine the circumstances are a bit different, from the problem I was having, then.

Comment: Installing ActiveTCL is certainly not necessary for MacPorts. It might not even be a suitable Tcl, because MacPorts currently does not work with MacPorts.